# How to select and view database with specific value?

Tags: java, sql, select

So I'm trying to search and print the value from the PHPMyAdmin database. But the result shows all row which has variable with containing the value. Like when I try search variable `int bulan` that has value 2. This also shows a row that has a value of 12, 22 or 23 as a result.

this is my code

```
System.out.print("Masukkan bulan yang ingin ditampilkan [mm]: ");
                var.mnip=input.nextLine();
                try{
                String sql="SELECT * FROM lembur " + "where bulan like('%" + var.mnip + "%')";
                st= (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println ("");
                        System.out.println ("Nomer Input       :"+rs.getString("number"));
                        System.out.println ("Nama              :"+rs.getString("nama"));
                        System.out.println ("NIP               :"+rs.getString("nip"));
                        System.out.println ("Divisi            :"+rs.getString("divisi"));
                        System.out.println ("Waktu Lembur      :");
                        System.out.println ("dd/mm/yyyy");
                        System.out.println ("\tTanggal :"+rs.getString("tanggal"));
                        System.out.println ("\tBulan   :"+rs.getString("bulan"));
                        System.out.println ("\tTahun   :"+rs.getString("tahun"));
                        System.out.println ("Keterangan Lembur :"+rs.getString("ket_lembur"));
                        System.out.println ("Lama Lembur       :"+rs.getString("divisi"));
                        System.out.println ("");
                        System.out.println ("======================================");
                        System.out.println ("");
                  }
                }
                catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println("Data Ada Kesalahan" + e.toString());
                    }
```

Comment: That is what `like(%...)` does. If you want to find that one that _equals_ the value 2, then you should use `=`.

Comment: Your where clause is "where bulan like('%" + var.mnip + "%')".  If you want to an exact query change it to where bulan = var.mnip.

Comment: Thanks for replying I tried to edit it like this:
` String sql="SELECT * FROM lembur " + "where bulan = var.mnip "; `
but the result is like this :
Data Ada Kesalahan com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'var.mnip' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like operator gives all matches where value 2 is in there that's why you get 12, 22 or 23 in the output you should use `equal to operator` for an exact match.

[Read More about Like operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm)

```
               System.out.print("Masukkan bulan yang ingin ditampilkan [mm]: ");
                var.mnip=input.nextLine();
                try{
                String sql="SELECT * FROM lembur " + "where bulan=" +var.mnip;
                st= (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println ("");
                        System.out.println ("Nomer Input       :"+rs.getString("number"));
                        System.out.println ("Nama              :"+rs.getString("nama"));
                        System.out.println ("NIP               :"+rs.getString("nip"));
                        System.out.println ("Divisi            :"+rs.getString("divisi"));
                        System.out.println ("Waktu Lembur      :");
                        System.out.println ("dd/mm/yyyy");
                        System.out.println ("\tTanggal :"+rs.getString("tanggal"));
                        System.out.println ("\tBulan   :"+rs.getString("bulan"));
                        System.out.println ("\tTahun   :"+rs.getString("tahun"));
                        System.out.println ("Keterangan Lembur :"+rs.getString("ket_lembur"));
                        System.out.println ("Lama Lembur       :"+rs.getString("divisi"));
                        System.out.println ("");
                        System.out.println ("======================================");
                        System.out.println ("");
                  }
                }
                catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println("Data Ada Kesalahan" + e.toString());
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get values with an `int` input

```
SELECT * FROM lembur where bulan = 2
```

if you want to search for `string` varaible starting with '2'

```
SELECT * FROM lembur where bulan like '2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

> String sql="SELECT * FROM lembur " + "where bulan = ('var.mnip')";

When you use 'like' then the query will give a result where output will contain the value and not the exact value, therefore your code is gave 'bulan' containing '2' in it and not 'bulan' with value '2'

Plz let me know if it isnt working :)